# Annoying glitch that won't let me finish the "Discerning the Transmundane" quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On [the quest where you get the Oghma Infinium book](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane), I encountered a glitch that won't let me finish it, after transcribing the damn thing and returning the Lexicon to Septimus I was expecting the usual, to be told to hunt down all the blood required, but instead the nutcase did something he's never done before, he told me he'd "contact" me once he's deciphered it.

Well I thought maybe it had something to do with Dawnguard since on the vampire quests you go after that Elder Scroll, long story short and about 20 level ups later I killed Harkon, finished the vampire quests, went back to Septimus and still he will not give me the second part of the quest, this of course means no Oghma Infinium so... no level 81 and no using perk points unless I wanna grind till ten years from now and I might be close.

Anyways, I am extremely pissed at this. Has anyone else had this happen and is there any possible way to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

From the [UESP article about that quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane):

> To continue past this point, you must be level 15 or higher. If you aren't level 15 yet, giving Septimus the Lexicon will result in him dismissing you; then, you must wait until a courier delivers a letter from him to continue.

I don't know why the letter hasn't triggered, but you could use the console command `setstage DA04 40` to force yourself to the next stage of the quest.

Alternatively you could try leaving and returning to towns to trigger a courier.

Comment: It was before lvl 15 that i did the quest too, then he dismissed me. After I leveled to 15 I fast traveled to a city and the courier came and gave me te note to talk to Septimus.

Comment: "*From the uesp article you linked..."*" It wasn't OP who linked the UESP article, it was I who edited the link in.